# gdb how to examine memory backwards

Tags: debugging, gdb, stack-trace

If I have an address 0x7ffffffff000, which is top of the stack. I want to exam the entire content of my stack, so I need to display it towards lower addresses.

Currently, I do

```
x/16x 0x7ffffffff000-64
```

but this still display from low to high.

```
0x7fffffffefc0: 0x782f756c  0x68747561  0x7469726f  0x43430079
0x7fffffffefd0: 0x45484341  0x5341485f  0x52494448  0x682f003d
0x7fffffffefe0: 0x2f656d6f  0x756c7079  0x7065722f  0x652f736f
0x7fffffffeff0: 0x742f7078  0x00747365  0x00000000  0x00000000
```

What I want is something like this

```
x/-16x 0x7ffffffff000
0x7fffffffeff0: 0x742f7078  0x00747365  0x00000000  0x00000000
0x7fffffffefe0: 0x2f656d6f  0x756c7079  0x7065722f  0x652f736f
0x7fffffffefd0: 0x45484341  0x5341485f  0x52494448  0x682f003d
0x7fffffffefc0: 0x782f756c  0x68747561  0x7469726f  0x43430079
```

Is there some magic gdb command that will do what I want?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this message](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2016-08/msg00134.html), this feature has been added lately to gdb 7.12:

> GDB now supports a negative repeat count in the 'x' command to
>        examine memory *backwards* from the given address.

You would just have to type:

```
(gdb) x/-16x $rsp
```

Comment: He want to print the same content which is formatted backwards by address, not the content backwards.